# Intersection of lines with polygons query returns 0 entries

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I have the following query that intersects a linestring with a polygon, which used to return all the intersected and non-intersected lines, but the query returns zero entries successfully now.  I'm at a loss on what is wrong.  There is an obvious line/polygon intersection between them.

```
CREATE TABLE split_lines AS
SELECT
  p.lic_li_no,
  l.descriptor,

  ST_Intersection(p.geom,l.geom) AS geom
FROM
  public.pipeline_test_multi p, public.lsd_test l
WHERE
  ST_Intersects(p.geom, l.geom) and not ST_CoveredBy(p.geom, l.geom)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  p.lic_li_no, 
  l.descriptor,
  p.geom AS geom
FROM
  public.pipeline_test_multi p, public.lsd_test l
WHERE
  ST_CoveredBy(p.geom, l.geom);
```

[image]

Comment: What are the SRIDs of the layers? ("Project on the fly" means they'll draw, not compare)

Comment: The feature id for tables public.pipeline_test_multi and public.lsd_test were different (gid & id).

Comment: It was the gid and id mixup I think.

Comment: Not likely, since those play no role in spatial operators.

Comment: Do you mean that it works for you now?

Comment: @user30184 yes, it works now.

Comment: @Vince, I'm now not sure what else changed.  You are likely correct, but I don't know how to get it to not work now.